# Googleapis receiving token without clientSecret

Tags: node.js, google-api

Following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) page I've been trying to authorize user on desktop without using the clientSecret.
Althou As it was pointed to me, token url given in the url doesn't exist. Does anyone know a way to authorize user without using the clientSecret?

Comment: welp, the first error means **nope, the URL doesn't exist bro** and the second means **yhea you used this too much today, come back tomorrow**

Comment: @JSelser That is hardly a polite way to answer a question. I've kinda blindly used the google's url without checking it's availability, I will modify my question then. As for the limit, I was aware even in my question since I've stated that I assume it's due to not using the token.

Comment: Mmm, I didn't mean to be rude. Seems that my comment helped though

Comment: @JSelser I'm sorry then. I misinterpreted.